# Proof that the cardinality of an uncountably infinite set $S$ is equal to the cardinality of $S\setminus \{x\} $, $ x $ being an element of $S$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I have to prove that for some uncountably infinite set $ S$ and $x \in  S$  the cardinality of $S$ is equal to the cardinality of $S \setminus \{x\}$.

I have proven that this is the case for countably infinite sets but I cannot figure out how to prove if for uncountable sets.

Comment: What axioms for set-theory are you using ? How formal an answer do you want ?

Comment: Hint : Assume S/{x} is countable. What can we say about $S$ ?

Comment: This can't be proven without a little choice

Comment: It doesn't matter the set is countably infinite or uncountable, the result is true for every infinite set. And not only single element, one can remove a finite set of elements from that infinite set without changing it's cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter the set is countably infinite or uncountable, the result is true for every infinite set. And not only single element, one can remove a finite set of elements from that infinite set without changing it's cardinality.

$S$ be an infinite set and $A  \subset S$ be any finite set.

Claim : $Card(S)=Card(S\setminus A)$

Proof: Since $A$ is finite, assume $$A\sim\mathbb{N_n}$$ for some $n\in \Bbb{N}$.

Let, $A=\{x_1,x_2,,...,x_n\}$

Then by Axiom of choice, there exists a choice function

$$f: {\scr{P}}(S)\to S $$

such that $f(E) \in E \space$,  $\emptyset \neq E\subset X$

Then define,

\begin{align}x_{n+k} &=f(S\setminus \{x_1,x_2,...,x_{k}\})&k=1,2,... \end{align}

Now, define a map $$h:S\to S\setminus A$$ by

\begin{equation}
  h(x) =
    \begin{cases}
      x_{n+k} & \text{; } x=x_k\\
      x & \text{ otherwise }
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

Then, $h$ define a bijection.

Hence, $Card(S) =Card(S\setminus A) $

In your question the set $A$ is a singleton set. The proof is same. Try by yourself. Thanks.

Comment: Do you define $x_{n+k}$ for all natural number $k$? What did you mean by $k=1,2,…,n$?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. $x_{n+k} $ is defined for all natural numbers , $k=1, 2,3,...$

Comment: You need AC a second time to prove the existence of $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ which is OK because AC has been shown to be necessary for this Q.

Comment: Yes Sir. In first place I also need to use AC to find the sequence $(x_n)$ . Thank you Sir.